# Doctrine Question?

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

(i)

```
FROM User u 
LEFT JOIN u.Phonenumbers where u.level > 1
```

What is `u` , I assume it is just an ALIAS to `User` ?

(ii)

```
$profile = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->from('Profile p')
  ->innerJoin('p.User u')
  ->where('p.id = ?', 1)
  ->fetchOne();
```

What is `p` and `u` here ?

Need to quickly learn Doctrine ?
Please can anyone help ? 
Thanks for your TIme , Cheers !

Comment: If it's a question of doctrine, we need the [Spanish Inquisition](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gldlyTjXk9A).  No-one expects the Spanish Inquisition!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(i)  Yes, `u` is an alias for the `User` table.

(ii) Here, `p` is an alias for the `Profile` table, and `u` is an alias for the `User` table. The phrase `p.User u` refers to a relationship between `User` and `Profile`.

Answer (score 1):

In pure SQL, to which this seems to be related, then 'p' and 'u' would be aliases for the longer table names.